# Reference a javascript property with a dynamic name

Tags: javascript

I'm using Vue.js and I am wondering how I can call a javascript property in a dynamic way. Let's say I pass an argument to a function like this:

```
filter: function(items) {
    this.countriesToFilter.splice(index, 1);
},
```

How can I replace the **countries** in my this.countriesToFilter call in a dynamic way so I end up with essentially:

```
this.itemsToFilter.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way?

```
filter: function(items) {
    var whatToFilter = items + 'ToFilter';
    this[whatToFilter].splice(index, 1);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

```
var name = "itemsToFilter";
var myArray = eval("this." + name);

// use myArray
```

You can also add a safety check so you don't call `splice` on undefined

```
if (typeof myArray != 'undefined') {
    myArray.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can imagine this working is if you pass a string to the function, and interpolate that string into the object-notation, using square-brackets:

```
filter: function(keyName) {
    this[keyName + 'ToFilter']splice(index, 1);
}
```

If your existing variable, `items` (from the question), contains a value of relevance within the function then you'd also need to pass that as an argument also:

```
filter: function(keyName, items) {
    this[keyName + 'ToFilter']splice(index, 1);
}
```